# onclick event not working in Safari?

Tags: jquery, safari, cross-browser, onclick

Cann't figure out why this is working everywhere but Safari??
I have this HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="tweet-btn" onclick="authenticateTwitter();">
<img src="img/sign-in-with-twitter.png" alt="">
</a>
```

and this JS:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var socialMediaServiceUrl = 
      // Staging
      "http://gameconnect.svc";

    var sessionFormat = "(S($))/";
    var sessionId;

    function format(s, value) {
      return s.replace("$", value);
    }

    function authenticateTwitter() {
      authenticate("Twitter");
    }

    function authenticateFaceBook() {
      authenticate("FaceBook");
    }

    function authenticate(applicationName) {
      $.ajax({
        url: format(socialMediaServiceUrl, "") + "/Authenticate?appName=" + applicationName,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (response) {
          sessionId = response.SessionId;
          window.open(response.Url);
        }
      });
    }
</script>
```

**EDIT: SAFARI'S POP-UP BLOCK WAS PREVENTING IT, ANY SOLUTIONS TO PREVENT THIS?

Comment: try surrounding your functions with the $(document).ready(function() { //... }); and check the firebug console when you click on that link

Comment: Wow, figured it out.  It was Safari's pop-up blocker which prevented it.  But Safari gives no warning, or indication the Pop-Block is preventing something.  Any good solutions around this??

Answer (score 1):

Do these changes fix it:

```
<a href="#" class="tweet-btn" onclick="authenticateTwitter(); return false;">
<img src="img/sign-in-with-twitter.png" alt="">
</a>
```

and

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var socialMediaServiceUrl = "http://gameconnect.svc"; // Staging
    /* IMPLICIT SEMICOLON INSERTION? */

    var sessionFormat = "(S($))/";
    var sessionId;

    function format(s, value) {
      return s.replace("$", value);
    }

    function authenticateTwitter() {
      authenticate("Twitter");
    }

    function authenticateFaceBook() {
      authenticate("FaceBook");
    }

    function authenticate(applicationName) {
      $.ajax({
        url: format(socialMediaServiceUrl, "") + "/Authenticate?appName=" + applicationName,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (response) {
          sessionId = response.SessionId;
          window.open(response.Url);
        }
      });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove that fancy `href="javascript:;"` attribute and it should work. 
Or define it as

```
 href="javascript:authenticateTwitter();"
```

and remove onclick.

Either one but not both to be short.

Answer (score 0):

Try either

```
<a href="#" class="tweet-btn" onclick="authenticateTwitter();">
<img src="img/sign-in-with-twitter.png" alt="">
</a>
```

or

```
<a href="javascript:authenticateTwitter();" class="tweet-btn">
<img src="img/sign-in-with-twitter.png" alt="">
</a>
```